# Can't find my error, keep getting "-1.#IND00"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I've written a program for my C-programming college course. No matter what, I keep getting an indeterminate error. I've manually checked my math, and nothing strange comes up. I've been searching all over the web for advice, but ultimately find the same thing: it has something to do with my operations. However, I don't think anything I've done is "weird".

If someone could help me spot my error, I'd be very grateful.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define C 3e8 //symbolic constant C

int main() {

/* Initalize variables, including the constant "pi" */
int l1=380E-9, l2=600E-9;
const float pi = 3.14;
float time1 = 1E-14,
    time2 = 5E-14,
    time3 = 8E-14;
/* I've split up each "y" variable to make it cleaner */
double ySOL1, ySOL2, ySOL3;
double y1_SOL1, y1_SOL2, y1_SOL3;
double y2_SOL1, y2_SOL2, y2_SOL3;


/* Equations to compute time=1E(-14)*/
y1_SOL1 = 3 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l1)*time1));

y2_SOL1 = 5 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l2)*time1));

ySOL1 = y1_SOL1 + y2_SOL1;

printf("The value of Y for Time_1 is: %f", ySOL1); //prints value of y for time1


/* Equations to compute time=5E(-14) */
y1_SOL2 = 3 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l1)*time2));

y2_SOL2 = 5 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l2)*time2));

ySOL2 = y1_SOL2 + y2_SOL2;

printf("\n\nThe value of Y for Time_2 is: %f", ySOL2); //prints value of y for time2


/* Equations to compute, time=8E(-14) */
y1_SOL3 = 3 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l1)*time3));

y2_SOL3 = 5 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l2)*time3));

ySOL3 = y1_SOL3 + y2_SOL3;

printf("\n\nThe value of Y for Time_3 is: %f\n", ySOL3); //prints value of y for time3

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you cannot find an error - there isn't one :-)

Comment: I am surprised your compiler did not warn about `int l1=380E-9`.  Insure your compiler warnings are enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dividing by zero. You variables `l1` and `l2` should be `float` or `double`. Because they are integers they are truncated to zero, which in a floating-point division will lead to positive or negative infinity. (That's what the text `-1.#IND00` means)

Side note: If you are doing floating-point calculations, you should probably use one of `float` or `double` throughout, preferably `double`. Also:

```
const float pi = 3.14;
```

That's a rough estimate, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `int` to `double` in below declaraion

```
double l1=380E-9, l2=600E-9;
```

Problem is you are deviding by zero in expression below:

```
y1_SOL2 = 3 * (sin(2 * pi*(C / l1)*time2));
```

Because, `l1` is `0`. You have declared it as `int` and assigning the value of `decimal` (`380E-9`) which will converting it to `zero`.

Comment: That makes sense. I really appreciate your answer. :)

However, if this is the case, how would I do it the way my professor wants it? [Here are his instructions for the program](http://pastebin.com/gW7FjhcR). He wanted me to make the l1 and l2 integer values--obviously I can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm, the professor apparently wants you to do the nanometre to metre conversion in the formula. I can't see the point, because that really doesn't make the physical quantities integers, but you can make the `l1` and `l2` variables integer wavelengths and multpy them with 1.e-09 in the formula.

Comment: @MOehm That makes sense. How come I can't just cast l1 and l2 in the equations?

Comment: @Nate: That would still make them zero. Also, they are already silently cast, because you divide a `double` constant by an `int` and the rules of C mandate that the `int` be "promoted" to `double`, making it an floating-point division. But your problem is that they are assigned the value zero - namely when the initial value you specified, `380E-9` is (silently) cast to an integer.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you for the explanation. I really appreciate it. The concept of `cast` is new to me. Thank you again!

Comment: @Nate Sorry for jumping late in discussion. Your sole point is you are trying to store 0.000000380 in to int which is not possible. If you try, will be converted into 0 anyway. So I am not sure why professor want to store that as int.